# Adding objects too list in python

Tags: python

I have a list that I add lists to (I'll call it list1) and the list I add to it I continuously modify(I'll call it list2). I have a problem where when I change list2 it changes all the lists in  list1, so list1 is storing list2 several times, but I want it too store the value of list2 when I add it. How do I make it store the values of list2 and not the object itself.
eg. I want this:

```
listB = ["a", "b"]
listA.append(listB)
print(listA)
listB.pop(1)
listA.append(listB)
print(listA)
```

to print this:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a']]
```

but it prints this:

```
[['a'], ['a']]
```

Comment: The first item of `listA` is *also* `listB` so what you do to one you have done to both (though there really is only one). Perhaps you want to `listA.append(listB).copy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't adding a copy of `listB` to `listA`; you are just adding the same reference to `listB` twice. `print(listA)` thus shows what `listB` looks like (twice) at the time of the call.

If you want to capture the state of `listB` at the time of the `append` operation, you need a copy of the list.

```
listA.append(listB[:])
```

Note that this is a shallow copy only.

Answer (score 0):

list.[extend](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable.

```
listB = ["a", "b"]
listA.extend(listB)
print(listA)
listB.pop(1)
listA.extend(listB)
print(listA)
```

result

```
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the same reference to (listb). print(lista) this will show what listb is but twice at the time of the execution of the command.
However, you will be needing to copy the list.
use this command listA.append(listB[:])